# In SSIS how do I access the result of running an OLE DB Command?

Tags: database, ssis, command, etl, ole

I am using SSIS within Visual Studio 2010. My package looks like:
OLE DB Source -> Multicast -> 7 OLE DB Command's

The sixth of the above mentioned seven OLE DB Command's contains:

```
SELECT r.DeviceID 
FROM   hub.ResolveDeviceInstanceToDevice r 
WHERE  r.DeviceInstanceID = ?
       AND r.DatasetID = ?
```

I wish to use the returned DeviceID in the seventh OLE DB Command. Can I do this? How? If not how should I do this?

I have put all 7 of the OLE DB Command beneath one Multicast, because several of them are using the same output from the OLE DB Source.

I am choosing not to use a stored procedure for this, because there is a preference to do this via ETLs. But if this is too complex, I'll consider moving to a stored procedure.

Comment: Just to confirm, all the above runs ok, but I don't see how to access the result of the select command.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old question, but I came across it doing a search for a similar problem.  The Lookup is probably a better solution to the statement you gave like Kyle answered, but you can do what you are asking by adding a parameter to the SQL statement.

```
SELECT ?=r.DeviceID 
FROM   hub.ResolveDeviceInstanceToDevice r 
WHERE  r.DeviceInstanceID = ?
   AND r.DatasetID = ?
```

So the first question mark will be param0 and will be the resulting column / field of the query.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be doing this with an OLE DB Command. Instead, you should use a Lookup task to achieve this.

1. Set your Lookup's connection to the database you're running the command against.
2. Set its query to

   SELECT r.DeviceID, r.DeviceInstanceID, r.DataSetID
   FROM   hub.ResolveDeviceInstanceToDevice r
3. In the columns, join your source's DeviceInstanceID and DataSetID inputs to the appropriate lookup columns.
4. Add the DeviceID as an Output column.

Now you can use this value in another OLE DB Command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with a `select`. Having a stored procedure, you could do

`exec ? = GetDeviceId ?, ?`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do this by writing the `DeviceID` output of the "OLE DB Command 6" to a Script Component. In that Script Component, write the input to a new destination. You should make that destination a temporary table. Drop the "OLE DB Command 7" and put its code as mere SQL code without parameters in the new Script Component so that you run a `select` query with a lookup join from that temporary table, like the other answer on the lookup says it as well, but instead in a Script Component in C#. A Script Component has input and output arrows and can run any SQL command. To see how you can fill the temporary table with the input dataset coming in with the green arrow (the output of "OLE DB Command 6"), see as an example [How do I create and fill a temporary table from a data source by means of a C# DataTable without ever leaving the SSIS Data Flow Task?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/338129/how-do-i-create-and-fill-a-temporary-table-from-a-data-source-by-means-of-a-c-d).

The trick of it all is that writing to an "OLE DB destination" does not have an output arrow so that you cannot make sure that your next steps is after the writing. But if you do this with a Script Component, you have input and output arrows. You can put it right beneath the "OLE DB Command 6" and will have all of the SQL power you can think of once that you put the input from "OLE DB Command 6" into a table again. Since you can put the Script Component after the "OLE DB Command 6", you can be sure that the step is not running in a synchronous way next to "OLE DB Command 6", but after it.